# SWIG and PHP7: Strange string vector behaviour

Tags: c++, swig, php-7

I am writing some wrapper code using SWIG to expose my C++ functions to PHP.

**my_module.i**

```
%module phpMyModule

%include "exception.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "typemaps.i"

// INPUT: convert PHP native array to std::vector<std::string>
%typemap(in) const std::vector<std::string> & %{
    if (Z_TYPE($input) == IS_ARRAY) {
        std::vector<std::string> temp2;
        $1 = &temp2;

        HashTable *ht = Z_ARRVAL($input);
        zval *data;
        HashPosition pos;
        for (zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(ht, &pos);
             (data = zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(ht, &pos)) != nullptr;
             zend_hash_move_forward_ex(ht, &pos)
        ) {
            convert_to_string(data);
            $1->push_back( std::string( Z_STRVAL_P(data), Z_STRLEN_P(data) ) );
        }
    }
    else SWIG_exception( SWIG_TypeError, "Type Error: Only PHP array is supported!" );
%}

%{
#include "MyModule.h"
%}

extern int initialize_engine( const std::string& script_file, const std::vector<std::string>& input_vars );
```

**SWIG generated wrapper code**

```
ZEND_NAMED_FUNCTION(_wrap_initialize_engine) {
    std::string *arg1 = 0 ;
    std::vector< std::string > *arg2 = 0 ;
    std::string temp1 ;
    zval args[2];
    int result;

    SWIG_ResetError();
    if(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 2 || zend_get_parameters_array_ex(2, args) != SUCCESS) {
        WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    }

    convert_to_string(&args[0]);
    temp1.assign(Z_STRVAL(args[0]), Z_STRLEN(args[0]));
    arg1 = &temp1;

    if (Z_TYPE(args[1]) == IS_ARRAY) {
        std::vector<std::string> temp2;
        arg2 = &temp2;

        HashTable *ht = Z_ARRVAL(args[1]);
        zval *data;
        HashPosition pos;
        for (zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(ht, &pos);
             (data = zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(ht, &pos)) != nullptr;
             zend_hash_move_forward_ex(ht, &pos)
        ) {
            convert_to_string(data);
            arg2->push_back( std::string( Z_STRVAL_P(data), Z_STRLEN_P(data) ) );
        }
    }
    else SWIG_exception( SWIG_TypeError, "Type Error: Only PHP array is supported!" );

    result = (int)initialize_engine((std::string const &)*arg1,(std::vector< std::string > const &)*arg2);

    RETVAL_LONG(result);
thrown:
    return;
fail:
    SWIG_FAIL();
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

    require_once '<path>/<to>/phpMyModule.php';

    $handle = phpMyModule::initialize_engine(
        '<path>/<to>/test.script',
        ["var1", "var2", "var3"]
    );

    echo "Handle #1 Value: $handle\n";
    phpMyModule::terminate_engine($handle);

?>
```

Basically what the above code does is to call `_wrap_initialize_engine()` with a PHP string (`script_file`) and a PHP array of variable names (`input_vars`). SWIG uses the `typemap` to convert the PHP string and array to std::string and std::vector accordingly, and then calls the real `initialize_engine()`.

In `initialize_engine( const std::string& script_file, const std::vector<std::string>& input_vars )` I have:

```
std::for_each( input_vars.begin(), input_vars.end(), [&]( const std::string& name ) {
    std::cout << "Adding " << name << " ..." << std::endl;
    // signature is Data::addVariable( const std::string& name, const VariableVector& values );
    // Data::VariableVector is actually std::vector<double>
    data.addVariable( name, Data::VariableVector() );
} );
```

This works. The print out is

```
Adding var1 ...
Adding var2 ...
...
```

But if I comment out the `std::cout ...`, all calls to `data.addVariable()` will receive an empty string for the `name` argument. (I know this because inside the call I test the name against existing names and throw an error when duplicates are used. Without the `std::cout ...` I got error saying "the name '' already exist"...)

**My Question**

How could this happen? A `const std::vector<std::string>&` should not be affected by whether or not I call `std::cout` on it.

My only guess would be that std::string re-used the char* points instead of copying them? If this was the case then the real buffers are still inside PHP and may have been changed? I believe this should not be the case but just want someone with better knowledge in C++ to confirm that for me.

But if this was not the case, then why does the above strange behaviour happen?

Comment: std::string makes a copy.

Comment: The posted code looks ok. It's hard telling what could be causing the problem you are seeing. One thing you can do to troubleshoot the problem is to add a few lines of code to print the contents of `temp2` just before the call to `my_cpp_function`.

Comment: @RSahu I added another std::cout right before the call to `my_cpp_function()` and the output is correct. However using or not using the std::cout inside my_cpp_function still generate different results.

Comment: What is the signature for `data.addVariable`()?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a stupid error I made... Sorry...

**my_module.i**

```
%module phpMyModule

%include "exception.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "typemaps.i"

// INPUT: convert PHP native array to std::vector<std::string>
%typemap(in) const std::vector<std::string> & %{
    std::vector<std::string> temp2;  // should be declared here!
    if (Z_TYPE($input) == IS_ARRAY) {
        // if declared here, temp2 will be released before init_engine() was called!
        // Wrong: std::vector<std::string> temp2;
        $1 = &temp2;
        ......
}
else SWIG_exception( SWIG_TypeError, "Type Error: Only PHP array is supported!" );
```

%}